# Dynamic default value for Kendo Grid

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I want an `auto increment` column in my Kendo Grid. This field isn't server side auto increment, because I want the user to see the value and be able to change it.

My current solution is to add a `click` attribute to `Create` button and loop over rows to find the highest value and increment it.

But how can I insert this value inside the newly created row? `Click` event happens before the new row is created.

So there is two possible solution:

1. Have a variable as default value and update it in my JS code.
2. Access the newly created row somehow, and update the value.

This is my JS code:

```
function createClick(id) {
    var grid = $("#" + id).data('kendoGrid');
    var highestRadif = 0;
    grid.tbody.find('>tr').each(function () {
        var dataItem = grid.dataItem(this);
        var radif = dataItem.SRadifReqR;
        highestRadif = highestRadif < radif ? radif : highestRadif;
    })
    alert(++highestRadif);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use Grid's `edit` event to add your new `generatedId` value to new Grid's `model`.

This is some explanation from their [**documentation**](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#events-edit):

> **Edit**
>
> fired when the user edits or creates a data item.
>
> - **e.container** *jQuery*, jQuery object of the edit container element, which wraps the  editing UI.
> - **e.model** *kendo.data.Model*, The data item which is going to be edited. Use its isNew method to  check if the data item is new
>     (created) or not (edited).
> - **e.sender** *kendo.ui.Grid*, The widget instance which fired the event.

I suppose your click have something like this

```
//generate id code
vm.newId = ++highestRadif; // we need to store generated Id
grid.addRow();
```

then on edit event

```
edit: function(e) {
    var model = e.model; // access edited/newly added model
    // model is observable object, use set method to trigger change event
    model.set("id", vm.newId);
}
```

**Note**: Your schema model's field must set property `editable: true`, due to enable us to change model field value using `set` method. Also if your field schema have validation required, you need to remove it.

```
model: {
    id: "ProductID",
    fields: {
        ProductID: { editable: true, nullable: true },
    }
}
```

[**Sample**](http://dojo.telerik.com/@diondirza/uJILU)

Comment: What do you mean by `vm`? What's that?

Comment: It is just view model variable. if you don't use view model object, you could use window scope variable (e.g `window.newId` )

Comment: It'll be much easier to write the entire method inside `Edit` function. Do you know how can I get the `Grid` from `e`? Thanks for your help and attention.

Comment: Dion it works fine for Integer fields, but it doesn't work for bytes. Any tricky parsing?

Comment: What's byte and what's integer field? Do you mean you want to assign model ID with bytes value?

Comment: No, I mean in the C# Model they have `byte`, `int16` Type. I don't know maybe there's some other problem.

Comment: Still, I don't get it sir, whether you want to assign bytes field with integer value or integer with bytes value?

Comment: The field is byte, but I don't really care. I just want to assign a number to it.

Comment: Sorry Dion, someone had changed my model and set that field to read only. So I wasn't able to change it and I thought it has something to do with the field's type. It works fine :)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to put a function in the datasource schema for this.

```
schema: {
    model: {
        id: "id",
        fields: {
            currencyType: { defaultValue: getDefaultCurrency },
            invoiceDate: { type: "date" }
        }
    }
}

    function getDefaultCurrency() {
        return _.find(vm.currencyTypes, { id: vm.currencyId });
    };
```

Comment: My forms didn't post when I did it this way, but using parameterMap worked: `if (type === "create") { data.id = kendo.guid(); }`