# Getting Kendo Grid's ID Field WithJavascript

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a function that I'm going to use with several different Grids. In this function I want to set Grid's Id field which varies in different Grids.

How can I get each grid's ID?

```
function incId(e) {
    var model = e.model;
    var grid = e.sender;
    //removed 
    model.set(!IDFIELD!, ++Id);
}
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to get property name for ID?

Comment: Yes, which I've set like this: `model.Id(x => x.TDocCode);`

Comment: You declare your grid manually with razor right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `model.idField` to get it

```
model.set(model.idField, ++Id);
```

Please read its [documentation](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/model) for further investigation

Comment: It works fine. If you remember from your [last answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30419736/dynamic-default-value-for-kendo-grid/) I was trying to increment the ID. I'm not much familiar with JS, how can I rewrite this line: `dataItem.SRadifReqR`

Comment: Javascript object can be accessed like an array field, so you can access that property similar like this `dataItem["SRadifReqR"]`, so if you can't guess what is the name of field `id`, you could turn it out to be like this `dataItem[dataItem.idField]`